# BigQuery SQL returning double the rows that exist

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This query returns double the rows that I intend to retrieve.  This user has exactly 2 records for event_name = 'level_completed' but I'm getting 4.  What I want are the two rows like this:

| event_date | user_pseudo_id | app_id | country | first_open | level | level_success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230831 | 001 | a | Brazil | date1 | 0 | Failure. |
| 20230915 | 001 | a | Brazil | date1 | 1 | Success. |

But I get duplicates for each.  *Both the top query and bottom query each separately only return 2 rows.*

The data looks like this with event_params as a record.
[image: events and events params as a record]

```
SELECT 
  learner_cohort.event_date,
  learner_cohort.user_pseudo_id,
  learner_cohort.app_id,
  learner_cohort.country,
  learner_cohort.first_open,
  level_data.level,
  level_data.level_success
 FROM
(
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_date, app_info.id AS app_id, geo.country AS country,user_first_touch_timestamp AS first_open
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT * FROM `ftm-b9d99.analytics_159643920.events_20*`
    WHERE PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
    and event_name = 'level_completed'
    AND  user_pseudo_id like '942389096%'


  )
  GROUP BY user_pseudo_id, app_info.id, geo.country,event_date,user_first_touch_timestamp
) AS learner_cohort
left JOIN
(
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, level, level_success
  FROM
  (
    SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_date ,
    max(CASE WHEN params.key = 'level_number' THEN params.value.int_value END) as level,
    max(CASE WHEN params.key = 'success_or_failure' THEN params.value.string_value END )as level_success
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT * FROM `ftm-b9d99.analytics_159643920.events_20*`
      WHERE PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
    ),
    UNNEST(event_params) AS params
    WHERE event_name LIKE 'level_completed'
    AND user_pseudo_id LIKE '942389096%'

    GROUP BY user_pseudo_id,event_date

  ) 
) 
AS level_data ON learner_cohort.user_pseudo_id = level_data.user_pseudo_id
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: If both queries return each return two records, and user_pseudo_id=001 in all the records then when you join them on user_pseudo_id you will obviously get 4 records in your final result (2x2 = 4)

Comment: @drum Data looks similar to this - with events and event_params as a record: https://blog.sheetgo.com/integrations/how-to-use-unnest-in-bigquery/

Comment: @NickW Can you show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself in a simpler way.  It comes down to learning that you can use multiple UNNEST on the same record to get multiple key/values.

```
SELECT ga.event_name, app_info.id, level_params.key , level_params.value.int_value as level, success_params.key,success_params.value.string_value as level_success, geo.country,user_first_touch_timestamp
FROM `ftm-b9d99.analytics_159643920.events_20*` AS ga,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS level_params,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS success_params
WHERE
  ga.event_name = 'level_completed'
  AND level_params.key = 'level_number'
  AND success_params.key = 'success_or_failure'
```